# Regular expression to split() the string into 2 parts. Any letters and everything after

Tags: python

Input string, output - list with 2 strings:
A few examples:

```
str1 = dir/?
str2 = dir c:\users /A/B
str3 = dir>1.txt

list1 = ['dir', '/?']
list2 = ['dir', ' c:\users /A/B'] #with space
list3 = ['dir', '>1.txt']
```

Comment: on what basis is the underscore being included in 4?

Comment: Explain a bit more for us. Your title makes me think that you want to split a string in half at the spot before the first non-alphabetical character, but the fourth example you've provided runs counter to that.

Comment: Im delete expample4, underscore is not so important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r"([a-zA-Z_]+)(.*)"` should do it, though I'm confused about the presence of the underscore in #4, since you wrote "any letters" in the title.

to actually use this in code:

```
import re
str1 = "dir/?"
m = re.match(r"([a-zA-Z_]+)(.*)", str1)
list1 = list(m.groups()) #list1 is now ['dir', '/?'], as desired
```

If you don't actually want the underscore, then just remove it from the first character class: `r"([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)"`

Comment: Didn't you get the memo? `_` was added to the alphabet in the middle of elemenop

Comment: You could use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: @MaximAnatol'evichBorovsky `\w` includes numbers.

Comment: @Barmar yes, sorry

Comment: @Personman have a problem with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: @Keymaster sorry, i had the argument order switched (and also missed parens in the call to groups() on the last line). i edited it so it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
str1 = 'dir/?'
j = s[:str1.index('r')+1:],s[str1.index('r')+1:]
list1 = list(j)
```

Also try.

```
list1 = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)',str1)[1:]
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful for you to include a bit more info, but in Python, you could avoid regular expressions by using the `.split()` function and limit the output to 2 parts:

```
str = "dir c:\\users /A/B"
str.split(" ", 2)
# ['dir', 'c:\\users', '/A/B']
```

If you have to field the possibility of no spaces, you could use `lstrip` to remove the prefix and then remove any whitespace.

```
str.lstrip('dir').lstrip()
```

Note the extra backslash to escape the backslash in the string.

Regular expressions are more flexible for sure, but sometimes the simpler solutions can be appropriate depending on your use case.

Comment: Updated to handle the 1st example (I may be going senile, but I think the examples changed while I was writing this)

Comment: I also don't think you understand how `lstrip()` works. That will also remove `rid`, `di`, `r`, `dirir`, etc.